# Dataproc adding extra field when adding keys using --properties?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to update or add new fields to hive config in dataproc cluster using --properties field. I am running dataproc cluster command from cloud shell. What i am seeing is dataproc is adding new key with final. I am unable to find what it means?

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.compactor.worker.threads</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <final>false</final>
    <source>Dataproc Cluster Properties</source>
  </property>
```

Also when does dataproc applies these changes to hive.xml? after hive service start running on the cluster or before ?
Also i am unable to find any documentation for how to restart hive and spark after making some changes to hive config after cluster creation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If a property is marked `final`, it cannot be overriden by users on a per-job basis (e.g. using command line parameters or setting properties in SparkConf/Configuration). We have explicitly made cluster-wide properties overridable. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html

2) Dataproc applies [--properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) to the xml files before starting any services

3) If you manually change properties, you can restart the services relevant services by ssh'ing into the master node of the cluster and running `sudo systemctl restart <service>`. For hive, that's `hive-metastore` and `hive-server2`. For spark, that's `spark-history-server`. Several [initialization actions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) do this.

4) Consider deleting and recreating your cluster if you want to change properties -- that's a bit easier than figuring out what services to restart.

5) Remember that you can still set per-job configs on a per-job basis. If you're using gcloud, that's something like `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.executors.cores=4 ...other args...`, with `spark-submit` you can use `--conf`, and with hive, you can use `set prop=value`.

Comment: I believe Dataproc has grown up now. It allow most of these functionality from UI itself and much more functionality.